# Can't delete object with axios

Tags: mongodb, axios

I have a function `deleteBook` which sends data through axios to a server for deletion.
The data logs on the `deteBook` function but it does not delete in the database.

**Component**

```
deleteBook = () => {       
    const existingBook = {
        id: this.props.data[0]._id,
        title: this.props.data[0].title,
        author: this.props.data[0].author,
        isbn: this.props.data[0].isbn,
        // noOfCopies: this.state.noOfCopies,
    };
    console.log(existingBook);

    axios.delete('/api/book/delete', existingBook)
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .then(this.toggleAlertSuccess)
        .catch(this.toggleAlertFail);
}
```

**Server**

```
router.delete('/delete', (req, res) => {   
    Book.findOneAndDelete({isbn: req.body.isbn})
        .then(book => res.json(book))
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
})
```

Comment: can you try what you get on the server side by log `req.body`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `req.params` on server side.

> As `axios` is not pass parameter in body for `delete` req.

```
Book.findOneAndDelete({isbn: req.params.isbn})
        .then(book => res.json(book))
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```